# Android layout- relative vs frame

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I have an application where I want to achieve a layout where the product image will be in the background and top of that to the right bottom, I want to place the price of the product and to the left bottom  I want to place an add button.

Should I use frame layout or relative layout ???

Comment: could you explain by screen drawing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FrameLayout vs RelativeLayout for overlays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875453/framelayout-vs-relativelayout-for-overlays)

Answer (score 0):

As a practical rule, I think it's up to you. I personally tend to use RelativeLayouts because they're more flexible, but you can achieve the same effect with either.

This SO post explains the performance differences between the two layouts in more detail: [FrameLayout vs RelativeLayout for overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875453/framelayout-vs-relativelayout-for-overlays)

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout: When you have relation between siblings or parent.

Frame layout: When siblings are placed independent of each other and are only dependent on parent.

Based on your situation, you can opt in of any of these.

Answer (score 0):

My advice, If you have specific size for your background for each device, then go for relative layout, and set the background to your image. Because when using background in `RelativeLayout`, It'll fit the size of the relative layout itself, whether the image suits the size of the `RelativeLayout` or not. (Can be stretched/pixelated/Not properly added)

If you're not sure about specific size, you should use `FrameLayout`, with `ImageView`, that handles the `ScaleType`, which can be `centerCrop`, and it'll fit the layout in good shape.
And for the `TextView`, use `layout_gravity`, which will handle the position based on the parent layout.