# Maintain aspect ratio with LinearLayout.setBackgroundResource()

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `myLinearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_drawable)` to set the background of a `LinearLayout`. Is there any way to maintain the source image's aspect ratio (zooming to fit when necessary) when using this method instead of having the image stretch to fit the `LinearLayout`?

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

java file:

```
backgroundLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have to set the background of a layout (lets name it Layout_A), I use a RelativeLayout as parent and inside it I put 2 items:

- an ImageView with scaletype set to centercrop
- Layout_A

The xml would be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>

    <Layout_A>

        ...

    </Layout_A>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code you would need to change the background would be:

```
ImageView ivBackground = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.background);
ivBackground.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable));
```

or:

```
ImageView ivBackground = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.background);
ivBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

Comment: I used this answer, but with `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` for the root element: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22875453/1438339. In practice there is probably no difference and either should be fine I would imagine.